# How to interpret figure on somatic mutation frequencies

Tags: mutations

In paper [Mutational heterogeneity in cancer and the search for new cancer-associated genes](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v499/n7457/full/nature12213.html), Figure 1 defines:

> Somatic mutation frequencies observed in exomes from 3,083 tumour–normal pairs. Each dot corresponds to a tumour–normal pair, with vertical position indicating the total frequency of somatic mutations in the exome.

Is the figure representing with each point a tumor/normal pair because somatic mutations (differently from germline mutations) are assumed to not be present in the normal sample?